# How to COLLATE in Python Using mysql.connector?

Tags: mysql-python

I have the following query in MySQL workbench:

```
SELECT japanese
FROM my_table
where japanese = 'する' COLLATE  utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs;
```

When I try to pass the same query through the mysql.connector it blows up:

```
sql_query = 'SELECT japanese FROM my_table WHERE japanese = %s COLLATE  utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs LIMIT 1'

my_variable = (word_to_search,)
mycursor1.execute(sql_query,my_variable)
sql_excecuted = mycursor1.fetchall()
```

And I get the following error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
```

In the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-set-charset-collation.html) it says to update your connector settings, and I tried this:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = 'root',pwrd='123',database ='app')
mydb.set_charset_collation('utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs')
```

And get this error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Character set 'utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs' unsupported.
```

I'm feeling I'm in a catch-22 situation, there have been other issues with this program that have driven me to use the `utf-8` character set.  At the end of the day I'm reading a `.txt` file and creating an `html` document and am open to any character set that will allow the Japanese fonts to display correctly AND that I can search the `db` properly with.

Can someone help me understand the correct character set to use in this situation please?

Thank you!

Comment: `mydb.set_charset_collation('utf8mb4_bin')` ?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - You've been a saint to me this morning, thank you! Here's the error message I get: `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Character set 'utf8mb4_bin' unsupported.`